# Pythonic conversion from bit-string to bytes object (3.6.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, integer, integer-overflow

What is the pythonic way to convert a large bit-literal string to a 'bytes' object that can be sent over a socket?

`data=b'1010010110100101'`

`sock.sendto(bytes(int(data[i : i + 8], 2) for i in range(0, len(data), 8)), (IP, PORT))`

This method currently overflows with data of over 40 bytes, but much longer chunks (~1200 bytes) need ti be processed.  (presumably on the *int* casting).

I've tried a few other methods, but keep falling short.

When trying to convert `data` given above to `int` and then to `bytes`, everything works fine:

```
>>> data=b'1010010110100101'
>>> len(data)
16
>>> type(data)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> bytes(int(data[0:8],2))
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\...
...0\x00\x00'
```

The problem can be reproduced with longer data. For example, the following raises `MemoryError` during the casting to `int`:

```
>>> data2=b'10100101101001011010101010101010101010101010101010101010'
>>> len(data2)
56
>>> bytes(int(data2[:],2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
>>> int(data2[:],2)
46625523583593130
```

It's also possible to get an `OverflowError` when trying to pack `data2` into the maximum `int` size (`ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <= 36`):

```
>>> bytes(int(data2[:],36))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer
```

Comment: Hey @Ramrod, what do you mean exactly by `chokes` and `large`? What other methods have you tried?

Comment: Hi Aleksander, large was admittedly vague - updating the question.

Comment: `b'1010010110100101'` is already a bytes object

Comment: There is no such thing as a "bit-literal" string. What you have here: `data=b'1010010110100101'` is a *bytes* literal. What, **exactly** are you trying to send?

Comment: Thanks. Also, this is confusing: are you just casting to int and then back to bytes? Why? `>>> data=b'1010010110100101'
>>> type(data)
<class 'bytes'>
`

Comment: I'm pulling the error back up. The example from above was on another SO question, but I didn't 100% understand it.

Comment: The error seems to be with the call to `bytes`:
`>>> data2=b'101001011010010111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
>>> len(data2)
57
>>> type(data2)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> int(data2)
101001011010010111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>>> int(data2,2)
93251780174938111
>>> bytes(int(data2,2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
`

Comment: The memory overflows in your edits are because you're calling `bytes(...)` with a single, very large integer value. When you do this, python tries to create an array of zero-bytes of length equal to the value given it. If you pass a sequence, like in your original example, it will create a byte array of the values in that sequence.